# After mapster href doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, area, imagemapster

I'm trying to redirect a user on click of current floor

without

```
$('#mapimage').mapster(
{ 
    fillcolor: 'ff0000', fillOpacity: 0.40
});
```

href of area tag works. With this it doesn't. What have I done wrong?
[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/VcGXL/119/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#mapimage').mapster({
          fillcolor: 'ff0000',
          fillOpacity: 0.40,
          clickNavigate: true
      });
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VcGXL/120

You should read the documentation, everything is explained well ;)

> By default, ImageMapster will prevent the default browser behavior in image maps, and "select" areas when they are clicked.

http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?docs.html#clicknavigate